# how to create hyperlinks in R to move to the next sheet

Tags: r

I need help in R.

I have data of 3 departments sales, marketing, accounts data.
When exporting these data into excel, my desired output looks like of in the first sheet I need 3 rows of data i.e.: sales, marketing, accounts.

These 3 rows contains hyperlinks to the next sheets
When I click into sales it will takes me into the sales sheet as well as remaining.

Can any one help how this can be done?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your question related to R? Can you please show us what you have tried so far in R to create the Excel file(s)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [proding a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) and edit your post accordingly. I.e., provide input data, the expected output + what you tried and in what way it failed.

Comment: I exported multiple datasets (sales, marketing, account) into one excel files with different sheets, and also created hyperlink in excel but here what happens only web page hyperlinks is created but trying to assign hyperlinks to these 3 sheets within a file

Comment: Can i expect answer from any one

Comment: Please help me in this task

Comment: I used this code to give hyperlinks to the next sheet

library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1, 1:10) # 10 rows
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:8) # 8 columns
links <- c("D://r datasets/sales data.xlsx")
names(links) <- c("hyperlinks")
for (row in 1:length(links)) {
setCellValue(cells[[row,1]], names(links)[row])
addHyperlink(cells[[row,1]], links[row])
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "links.xlsx")
shell.exec("links.xlsx")

How to mention sheet name in this code

Answer (score 1):

To link to another sheet, use

```
addHyperlink(cell, "sheetname!colRow", linkType="DOCUMENT")
```

For example

```
library(xlsx) 
wb <- createWorkbook() 
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1") 
sheet2 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet2") 
rows <- createRow(sheet1, 1:10) # 10 rows 
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:8) # 8 columns 

row <- 1
link <- paste0(names(getSheets(wb))[2], "!", "A", row)
setCellValue(cells[[row,1]], "link to other sheet") 
addHyperlink(cells[[row,1]], link, linkType="DOCUMENT") 

saveWorkbook(wb, "links.xlsx") 
shell.exec("links.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank u for help i have a small doubt if already i have a excel file it contains sales, marketing, account sheets respectively file name is company details, i am little bit confusing how to give hyperlinks already exists excel file

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please post a specific coding problem. (Like you did in the comments, but add it to your posting in a code format for easy copy/paste)

Comment: I have sales data in excel file in that i have to open sheet3 
i tried below code but unable to give hyperlinks to sheet3
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1)
cells <- createCell(rows)
links <- c("[D://r datasets/sales data.xlsx]sheet3!")
names(links) <- c("link1")
for (row in 1:length(links)) {
setCellValue(cells[[row,1]], names(links)[row])
addHyperlink(cells[[row,1]], links[row])
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "hyperlinks to file.xlsx")
shell.exec("hyperlinks to file.xlsx")

Comment: You can do library(xlsx) 

wb1 <- createWorkbook() 
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb1, "Sheet1")
saveWorkbook(wb1, tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"))

wb2 <- createWorkbook() 
sheet2 <- createSheet(wb2, "Sheet2")
rows <- createRow(sheet2) 
cells <- createCell(rows) 
setCellValue(cells[[1,1]], "To Other File") 
addHyperlink(cells[[1,1]],sprintf("file:///%s#%s!%s", normalizePath(tf1, "/"), names(getSheets(wb))[1], "B2"), "FILE") 
saveWorkbook(wb2, tf2 <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"))
shell.exec(tf2)

Comment: Sorry not understanding ("file:///%s#%s!%s", normalizePath(tf1, "/")